# Array of structs conforming to protocol not recognized

Tags: swift, struct, protocols

I'm trying to create a method that takes an array of structs that conform to a protocol in Swift.

For the simplest example of this, I define an empty protocol and a method that takes an array of objects conforming to that protocol and just prints them

```
protocol SomeProtocol {}

func methodTakingProtocol(objects: [SomeProtocol]) {
    // do something with the array of objects
    print(objects)
}
```

When I try to feed this method an array of structs that conform to `SomeProtocol`, however, I get an error

```
struct SomeStruct: SomeProtocol {}

let arrayOfStructs = [ SomeStruct(), SomeStruct() ]

methodTakingProtocol(arrayOfStructs)
// ^ "Cannot convert value of type '[SomeStruct]' to expected argument type '[SomeProtocol]'"
```

Poking around a little, I've found that I can get around this problem by explicitly calling out `SomeStruct`'s adoption of `SomeProtocol`

```
let arrayOfStructs: [SomeProtocol] = [ SomeStruct(), SomeStruct() ]

// This will work
methodTakingProtocol(arrayOfStructs)
```

Can someone tell me what's going on here? Is this a bug that I should file a radar for, or is there some reasoning as to why the compiler doesn't recognize this array of structs as conforming to the protocol they have been marked as adopting?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. The compiler sees instances of `SomeStruct` and therefore sets the type of the array to `[SomeStruct]`. To change the type, you need to make your intent explicit. You might file a feature radar, though.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820240/assigning-an-array-of-structs-to-an-array-of-protocols.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually working as intended. In order to pass the array to the method you have to either cast it or explicitly declare it as the protocol:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {}

struct SomeStruct: SomeProtocol {}

// explicitly typed
let arrayOfStructs:[SomeProtocol] = [ SomeStruct(), SomeStruct() ]

func foo(bar:[SomeProtocol]) { }

foo(arrayOfStructs) // Works!
```

Here is an excellent article on this topic: [Generic Protocols & Their Shortcomings](http://krakendev.io/blog/generic-protocols-and-their-shortcomings)

> But that begs the question; Why can't we use generic protocols outside
>   of generic constraints?
>
> The short answer is: Swift wants to be type-safe. Couple that with the
>   fact that it's an ahead-of-time compiled language, and you have a
>   language that NEEDS to be able to infer a concrete type at anytime
>   during compilation. I can't stress that enough. At compile time, every
>   one of your types that aren't function/class constraints need to be
>   concrete. Associated types within a protocol are abstract. Which means
>   they aren't concrete. They're fake. And no one likes a fake.

edit: It's still a great article but upon re-reading I realized that it doesn't exactly apply here since we're discussing "concrete protocols" and not "generic protocols".

Comment: Thanks for that link! Definitely a lot of interesting information in that post, though, as you said, I'm not sure it's exactly what applies to this issue. I'm going to do some digging in Apple documentation when I get a chance to see if there's anything in there that might shed light on the situation.